# Yahoo finance CSV API and appid in PHP

Tags: php, api, csv, yahoo-finance

I've a small application retrieving stock data from Yahoo! working fine in my local server. When I uploaded it to a remote server it stopped returning data and showing a security error in FF: "This web site does not supply ownership information."

Then I realized I must apply for an application ID wich I did but still the problem remains:

```
$appid = urlencode('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx--'); // My App ID
...
$cHandle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($cHandle, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?appid='.$appid.'&s='.$symbol.'&f='.$properties.'&e=.csv');
curl_setopt($cHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$dataStr = curl_exec($cHandle);
curl_close($cHandle);
echo json_encode($dataStr);
```

Any idea what's wrong in my code? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Your error is not connected with your code - the Error in Firefox is related to the SSL certificate. As to why your code is not working - add some error checking around the CURL and see what that produces :

```
$appid = urlencode('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx--'); // My App ID
...
$cHandle = curl_init();
curl_setopt($cHandle, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?appid='.$appid.'&s='.$symbol.'&f='.$properties.'&e=.csv');
curl_setopt($cHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
...

if(curl_exec($cHandle) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($cHandle);
}
else
{
    echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
}

// Close handle
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Thanks for enlighten my mind. Code is working fine, the problem seems to be I'm using json_encode() function wich is part of PHP Core as of PHP 5.2.0. I have PHP 5.3.1 on my local server but 5.1.6 on the remote one. 
So, I'll have to install PECL json package or deal with the data on the client side as this PHP script is requested using jQuery.ajax()